# Angular-CLI: npm missing

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am a bit confused about the Angular-CLI and its requirements.

I have an existing and running angular project on my system.
It is running nicely. I can start the builtin server too with

```
ng serve
```

---

Now I tried to create a new project.
Create a directory and do this inside.

```
ng new MYTEST
```

But the output gives my an error.

```
installing ng
  create .editorconfig
  ...
  create tsconfig.json
  create tslint.json
Installing packages for tooling via npm.
/bin/sh: 1: npm: not found

Package install failed, see above.
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/npm-install.js:25
                    throw new Error(message);
                    ^
```

Files and directories were created but then npm is not found.
But is is installed and latest (Debian 10, npm is a virtual package for nodejs 6.14.3-1nodesource1).

I find

```
/usr/local/bin/npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
```

How can I get rid of that problem?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

```
> node -v
v8.0.0

> npm -v
bash: npm: command not found
```

Comment: what is the output of `npm --version`

Comment: npm as a binary is not found. You see in my post that is is pointing to a npm-cli.js

Comment: Did you intsall npm globally ?

Comment: Your install seems broken, your `/bin/sh` doesn't find `npm` command. To manage npm different version I'm using https://github.com/creationix/nvm on Ubuntu and macOS. There are many reasons why your npm install could be broken so...you should just reinstall it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check versions

   node -v
   npm -v
2. Reinstall NodeJS

   sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm
   curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
   sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
3. Check versions again.
4. Angualar CLI must be installed globally

   npm i -g @angular/cli

Comment: 4 is actually false

Comment: Yes and no. Theoretically you can use workarounds like https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5955#issuecomment-320273493 but its easier to use globally. Unless there is a reason to use different CLI versions on a system

Comment: Is there a good reason why not use the nodejs from the linux distro?

Comment: If I do so then npm is still not installed. nodejs is v8.11.2

Comment: It seems it is working on a vanilla machine but not on mine. maybe some problems with a former version I need to remove first. But it is not working with apt purge.

Comment: I use Ubuntu and its repositoryis version of nodejs has no Package Manager, so you have to install is separately. But I experienced incompatible issues a couple of times. It's easier to use nodejs repository itself

Comment: I removed the files manually and installed as told above. Works fine now.